# textplot_wordcloud group label highlight color

Tags: r, word-cloud, quanteda

I'm trying to replicate some `quanteda()` applications from this [post](https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2017-02-04/web/packages/quanteda/vignettes/plotting.html). Yet when I replicated their `textplot_wordcloud()` example on Presidential speeches, the group labels on my output does not contain highlight colors like grey-ish background in the example:

[image]

Since the `textplot_wordcloud()` function is inherited from `comparison.cloud()`, so I refer back to the latter's [document](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/wordcloud/versions/2.6/topics/comparison.cloud) to see if it has any arguments to set label highlight colors, but couldn't find any. I am wondering if it's possible to highlight group labels in `textplot_wordcloud()` with colors?

The replication code is attached at below.

```css
library(quanteda)
data(data_corpus_inaugural)

compDfm <- dfm(corpus_subset(data_corpus_inaugural, President %in% c("Washington", "Jefferson", "Madison")),
                groups = "President", remove = stopwords("english"), removePunct = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at an old example. You should look [here](http://quanteda.io/articles/pkgdown/examples/plotting.html) on the quanteda website for current plotting examples.

The function `textplot_wordcloud` has been rewritten and only uses internal quanteda calls so the reference to `wordcloud::wordcloud_comparison` is not really valid anymore. In this case you can't set the back ground color for the labels anymore. You can adjust the color and the size of the labels if you want to:

```
library(quanteda)
# Package version: 2.0.0
# See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

corpus_subset(data_corpus_inaugural, 
              President %in% c("Washington", "Jefferson", "Madison")) %>%
  dfm(groups = "President", remove = stopwords("english"), remove_punct = TRUE) %>%
  dfm_trim(min_termfreq = 5, verbose = FALSE) %>%
  textplot_wordcloud(comparison = TRUE,
                     labelcolor = "green",
                     labelsize = 2)
```